# Обработать нажатие ctrl+a

Tags: c++, c++builder

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Edit2KeyDown(TObject *Sender, WORD &Key, TShiftState Shift) 
    if (Shift.Contains(ssAlt) && Shift.Contains(ssCtrl))
```

Как изменить <kbd>Alt</kbd> на код клавиши <kbd>A</kbd>/<kbd>Ф</kbd>? Использование код клавиши (`65`) не помагает.

Comment: Напечатай переменную Key и будешь знать коды всех клавиш которые тебе нужны

Comment: `GetAsyncKeyState` пробовали?

Comment: @duracell Нет не пробовал

Comment: @alexus 65, я же написал что в условии прописал 65 и не сработало

Comment: @Евгений, добавил код в ответ, что не понятно спрашивайте.

Comment: Вы изменили вопрос, и теперь он стал непонятен. Можете написать чего вы хотите добиться меняя Alt на код клавиши A ?

Comment: @Alexus Код смотрите

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ((Shift.Contains(ssCtrl)) && (Key == 65))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


bool keydown(int key)
{
    return (GetAsyncKeyState(key) & 0x8000) != 0;
}

int main()
{
    while (!keydown(VK_ESCAPE))
    {
        if (keydown(VK_LCONTROL) && keydown('A'))
        {
            cout << "combo pressed!" << endl;
        }
        Sleep(10);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Будет ли работать программа если у меня русская раскладка? Вы видели что это не консольное приложение? Посмотрите мой ответ

Comment: Будет работать при любой раскладке и то, что я привел пример консольного приложения, не говорит о том, что не будет работать в "формах", главное Вам выдрать с примера функцию и поставить на нужное Вам событие или на "таймер".